# SUM rows by column unknown parameter - SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I've a table like this one

[image]

Where each customer has its own budget, and he/she spent it on some fruits. Budget isn't deduplicated by row (so Mike has 20 bucks to spend overall), whilst spent budget is purchase-specific (Mike has now 1 dollar to spend only)

I'd like to add a column that sum the overall spend by each customer in a non deduplicated way.

Like this:
[image]

I can't specify any WHERE clause, as I don't know all the names of the customers.

Any idea on how to go from one table to the other?

Thanks,
Carlo

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is incomplete, as it stands now, because instead of including the relevant data in your question, you have pasted external links.  Other users should not (and probably will not) have to patience to open those links to understand your problem.

Comment: Please read https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/ for an introduction on how to ask a good question regarding SQL. Then **[EDIT]** your question and add the missing information as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), do **NOT** post code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this query to achieve the data you need:

```
select 
    customer_name, 
    customer_budget, 
    purchase_type, 
    budget, 
    customer_budget - sum(budget) as remaining_budget
from Customers
group by customer_name, customer_budget, purchase_type, budget
```

Hope this helps :)